# Complex Mongo Shell Command conversion to Java Code

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a Mongoshell query which looks like

```
db.RemoteMongoData.aggregate([
        {$group: {
                "_id":"$IMEI Number",
        "Longitude":{"$last":"$Longitude"},
        "Latitude":{"$last":"$Latitude"},
        "Address":{"$last":"$Address"},
        "Timestamp":{"$last":"$Timestamp"},
            }},
        {$project: {
                 "IMEI Number":"$_id",
         "Longitude":"$Longitude",
         "Latitude":"$Latitude",
         "Address":"$Address",
         "Timestamp":"$Timestamp",
              }},
        {$sort: {
                'date': -1
            }}
    ])
```

I want to know how to convert this query, so that it can be executed using java.

Conversion "Longitude":{"$last":"$Longitude"} into equivalent java object is bugging me.
Please help..
From the sources available over the net, I have written a query which read like

```
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", "$IMEI Number")
    .append("Longitude", new BasicDBObject("$last","$longitude"))
    .append("Latitude", new BasicDBObject("$last","$latitude"))
    .append("Address", new BasicDBObject("$last","$address"))
    .append("Timestamp", new BasicDBObject("$last","$timestamp")));

    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("IMEI Number","$_id")
    .append("Longitude","Longitude")
    .append("Latitude","Latitude")
    .append("Address","Address")
    .append("Timestamp","Timestamp"));

    DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("date",-1));

    AggregationOutput output = dbCollection.aggregate(group,project,sort);
```

but still i'm facing error like

```
'exception: FieldPath 'Longitude' doesn't start with $' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "errmsg" : "exception: FieldPath 'Longitude' doesn't start with $", "code" : 16873, "ok" : 0.0 }
```

Can anybody rectify or point out what's wrong with my query, it'll be very helpful.
Please help..
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? Every time you see `{}` means that your Java code uses `Document()`. This could not be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me,

```
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",new BasicDBObject("_id","$IMEI Number")
    .append("Longitude", new BasicDBObject("$last","$Longitude"))
    .append("Latitude", new BasicDBObject("$last","$Latitude"))
    .append("Address", new BasicDBObject("$last","$Address"))
    .append("Timestamp", new BasicDBObject("$last","$Timestamp")));

    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("IMEI Number","$_id")
    .append ("Longitude",1)
    .append ("Latitude",1)
    .append ("Address",1)
    .append ("Timestamp",1));

    DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("date",-1));

AggregationOutput output = dbCollection.aggregate(group,project,sort);
```